WebdriverIO + Jasmine: How to make use of grep to filter the spec files
I have a suite folder with 3 spec files configured. In one of the spec file it block has the description "_smoke" but when using the jasmineOpts.grep=_smoke it does not filter the spec file instead it runs all the specs under the configured suite folder
I did follow the steps mentioned in the post
WebdriverIO + Jasmine: How to exclude a specific test file when running a suite based on that test file name
Note: I even tried hardcoding the grep value in jasmineOpts, that also did not work
Not sure what i am doing wrong here please suggest

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
